# How would I support 'taggable' content in MongoDb?

Tags: c#, mongodb, nosql

How would I go about implementing the following requirements in MongoDb:

- Records can contain text and or images, multiple fields, and are generally unstructured documents
- Records can be tagged with keywords, or key phrases
- Records are retrieved by searching using keywords and or key phrases
- It should be possible to combine keywords in searches using logical operators - AND, OR, NOT etc
- Making records themselves searchable is not required (though would be a nice to have)

I'm completely new to MongoDb so baby steps appreciated!

Comment: Your question is too broad

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a good match for questions that ask the community to solve your design questions. I'd suggest working on each question yourself and then see if you have specific programming questions you can't solve.

Comment: Since nearly all of you list involves text searching, you'll find that full text search isn't available for production use and may not provide the capabilities you specifically need.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky - Philipp managed to answer it just fine.

Comment: @WiredPrairie - thanks for the tip on full search. As for your other point, of course SO should be for design questions, programming is as much about design, more so arguably, than it is about 'why doesn't my function work'

Comment: @jimmy_terra too broad questions can be answered as well. As questions without valid reproducing code, or questions which shows minimal understanding of problem being solved

Comment: Start here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/ -- this covers what you should start with.

Comment: Question Nazis - sigh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB is designed for managing unstructured documents, so when your documents have different structures, MongoDB could be a good fit. But keep in mind that when you want to query your documents effectively, they should have a set of common fields to query by.

Keyword tagging can be done easily by storing all the relevant keywords in an array of strings with each document. MongoDB can transparently query arrays. When you have a document like this:

```
{
      somefield: "somevalue",
      someotherfield: "somemothervalues",
      tags: ["politics", "potato", "achieve world domination"]
}
```

you can find it with `db.collection.find({tags:"potato"})`. MongoDB can also index arrays transparently. When you create an index with `db.collection.ensureIndex({tags:1})` it will greatly enhance the speed of that query, even when you have many documents with many different combinations of keywords.

Regarding logical operators: MongoDB has these. See [$in](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) (OR-operator), [$all](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) (AND-operator for arrays) and [$nin](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) (not-operator for multiple values)

[Full text search](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/text/#dbcmd.text) is a feature which is currently marked as experimental. You can already play with it in development, but shouldn't use it in production yet.

Comment: Brilliant stuff Philipp, exactly what I was after, thanks...

Comment: thanks for this, this has got me up and running really quickly, much appreciated :)